Why are these Clow Cards under the Earthy Card?
Hmmmm..... Aside the rest (under the Earthy Card), why are these two Clow Cards (on the list below) under the Earthy Card?
List:

Libra Card
Loop Card

https://ccsakura.fandom.com/wiki/Clow_Cards
Hmmm.... I can definitely see and understand how the rest are related to the Earthy Card, but do the Libra Card and Loop Card have a connection with the Earthy Card compared to the rest?
Are there any significant reasons?
